# ethic vs ethics

Tags: differences

Would someone please compare these two? Or is [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2232883&p=11201439#post11201439) correct, even though it adduces nothing?

> As a noun (and not adj), [ethic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ethic?q=ethic) = A set of moral principles, especially ones relating to or affirming a specified group, field, or form of conduct:
>
> [ethics](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ethics?q=ethics) [usually treated as plural] = 1. Moral principles that govern a person’s behaviour or the conducting of an activity:

I do see that the second definition for ethics on that page differs from ethic.

Comment: The difference is your ***ethics*** usually means *all* the different [sets of] moral principles you're governed by. You can have *an ethic* in respect of a single aspect of human interactions, value judgements, etc., even if that ethic can actually be broken down into a number of [usually, interrelated] principles.

Comment: I would say *an* ethic is a moral character that one *projects,* through rhetorical performance or otherwise, while *one's* ethics are (as @FumbleFingers observes) the entirety of one's guiding principles of conduct, and *ethics* without determiner denotes a branch pf philosophy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you deduce this from the definitions above? If not, where did you find this difference?

Answer (score 3):

I came across this [article](http://slb-ltsu.hull.ac.uk/awe/index.php?title=Ethic_-_ethics) recently, and there is some good detail on the question here, which I think is articulated fairly well:

Ethic:

> refers to the set of moral values and principles which, taken collectively, guide and influence the life of a group or, less commonly, of an individual. We may speak, e.g., of the Puritan ethic, i.e., the set of moral values and principles which guide the lives of those who, like the Puritans, attach value to austerity and the rejection of sensual and worldly pleasures; or of the work ethic, i.e., the set of moral values and principles which guide the lives of those who believe in the moral value of work.

Ethics:

> (in the plural) is the code of behaviour considered appropriate to a particular group, especially a group defined by its occupation or profession. We may speak, e.g., of medical ethics, i.e., the code of behaviour that is considered appropriate for doctors, nurses, etc., in treating their patients; or of military ethics, i.e., the code of behaviour that is considered appropriate for soldiers and other members of the armed services. (You may like to think about the difference between military ethics and a military ethic.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't perceive the difference? Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as comments?